# control flow of program when using setInterval() in javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

really I don't understand the control flow of the program when using `setInterval()` in Javascript.
If we give a function that requires 100ms of time to execute as a parameter to `SetInterval()` method with time as 20ms as shown below

```
       setInterval(function{
                      for(var i=0;i<1000000;i++)
                           console.log(i)
                           },20);
```

when `setInterval()` calls it again after 20ms, then what happens??
thanx :)

***Adding***:
what is the main difference between simply looping and using setInterval for looping and using clearInterval for stopping??
check this http://www.sitepoint.com/multi-threading-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` is a Javascript Timer. Always remember: in Javascript, timer delay is not guaranteed. Since all JavaScript in a browser executes on a single thread, asynchronous events are only run when there's been an opening in the execution.

```
var some_function = function() { 
    for (var i=0; i < 1000000; i++) { 
        console.log(i); 
    } 
};
setInterval(some_function, 20);
```

When this example is executed, JavaScript starts the timer and in 20ms executes `some_function`

Assuming it takes 100ms for `some_function` to complete, what will happen ~100ms later when the function finishes executing is JavaScript will look around to see what has been waiting to execute.

It will find that ~20ms after the `setInterval` execution was started, another request was received to execute `some_function` (by the timer set by `setInterval`). At the time the command was received it could not be executed because JavaScript was busy running `some_function`.

Since there is nothing blocking the `setInterval` operation from occurring anymore, JavaScript will re-execute it. ~120ms have elapsed since the setInterval timer was started and your `some_function` will be apparently executing back-to-back.

Answer (score 1):

First let's start by fixing your javascript because you have some missing closing brackets:

```
setInterval(function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}, 20);
```

Which is equivalent to the following:

```
function loopAndDump() {
   for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
       console.log(i);
    }
}

setInterval(loopAndDump, 20);
```

or:

```
setInterval(function() { loopAndDump(); }, 20);
```

Now it's easier to understand what happens: the `loopAndDump` function is called at regular intervals at every 20ms. This function simply loops from 0 to 1000000 and dumps the counter to the console. And if you wanted to stop this process from executing the function at regular intervals you could use the [stopInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) function and pass it as argument the result returned by the setInterval function.

If you want to execute the function only once then you could use the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) method:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}, 20);
```

Now the loop will execute only once, 20ms after the javascript interpreter reaches the setTimeout line.

Comment: but when we look at this link http://www.sitepoint.com/multi-threading-javascript/
why simply looping is different from looping through setInterval method and using clearInterval for stopping??

Comment: The setInterval function allows you to execute some javascript code at regular intervals.

Comment: some other means? within the application? or within the browser??

Answer (score 0):

It won't be called again after 20 ms.

Javascript is strictly single threaded, so as long as your function is running, no events will be handled. The interval timer will trigger an event after 20 ms, but it won't be handled until your function finishes.